# Use ReactiveMongoRepository to find all ids only

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Mongo document using a custom id which has a basic structure. This productCode is represented as _id in the document when saved to the database

```java
        @Document(collection="products")
        public class Product {

          @Id
          private String productCode;
          // rest of fields...
        }
```

Here is the repository definition

```java
       interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepostory<Product, String>;
```

How can I get only the _ids from the database? I tried this but it did not produce any results, ids is empty:

```java
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        var fx = productRepository.findAll().map(p -> 
                 p.getProductCode()).collectList().doOnNext(
                 ids.addAll).subscribe();
```

If I do the same using log.info(c) in place of ids.addAll, it prints the individual product codes for example:

```java
                List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

        var fx = productRepository.findAll().map(c -> 
                                        c.getProductCode())
                .doOnNext(c -> log.info(c)).subscribe(c -> ids.add(c));
```